# Using a new value from an item to my sql statement without saving this value to database

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to compare a date value I just entered in my item (:P2007_Session_Date -it is a date picker-) with date values from my table. This new value has not yet been saved in my database.
How can i do that?
I am trying with DA but nothing happens

When:

Event: Change, item: P2007_Session_date

True Action Set Value:

SQL Statement

SELECT POLICIES.PRICE
  FROM POLICIES 
  WHERE POLICIES.ACTIVE = 1
  AND to_char(**:P2007_Session_Date**, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN to_char(POLICIES.START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_char(POLICIES.END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

Items to Submit

:P2007_Session_Date, :P2007_Price

Affected Elements

:P2007_Price

This gives me this error Ajax call returned server error ORA-01722: not acceptable number for Set Value.
but when i change my query from to_char(:P2007_Session_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') to to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') it works!
The problem is that i want to check not with sysdate but with the value that user just enter to :P2007_Session_Date item and it is not yet stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex items are strings, no matter what datatype they represent. So if you have a date value in a page item, you'll have to convert it to a date in your pl/sql. The statement `TO_CHAR(:P2007_SESSION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` is not correct, it expects the bind variable :P2007_SESSION_DATE to be of datatype DATE or TIMESTAMP, but since this is an apex item, it is just a string.

Cleanest solution is to just do a date comparison, not a character comparison (which would work in your case).

Give this statement a try instead:

```
SELECT
  policies.price
  FROM
  policies
 WHERE
  policies.active = 1 AND
  TO_DATE (:P2007_SESSION_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD' ) BETWEEN policies.start_date AND policies.end_date
```

Comment: Hi Koen and thank you for your response. Unfortunatendly a have a new error: Ajax call returned server error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where numeric was expected for Set Value.

Comment: That error does not indicate there is an issue with the date. I suggest you run the page in debug mode and investigate the debug entries for the ajax call. That should show where the error is raised and give you a clue why this is happening.

Comment: Your code works perfectly if i change :P2007_SESSION_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD' with sysdate (with no errors), but when i try to compare the value of this item have this error. Ι can not understand anything with the debug function ( i am very new at this)

Comment: The problem is with the format of my item (:P2007_SESSION_DATE). I need the format with hour and minutes (DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI) because i want to use this value for an appointments, but when i change the format to (MM-DD-YYYY) it works...

Comment: The "YYYY-MM-DD" of the statement needs to match the format mask of the page item. I assumed they were the same. Are they ?

Comment: Correct! I solved this issue by creating a hidden item and with DA i set a value to this item with the value of :P2007_SESSION_DATE but with the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' using SUBSTR.Thank you Koen for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. Could you flag the answer as correct please ?

Comment: @Apostolos one more remark - I don't think you need an additional item. Just change the "YYYY-MM-DD" to whatever format the page item is and you should be good.